# TLFTextField taking device fonts automatically in Flex Application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, fonts, flex4, flashbuilder4

I am using a Flex Application,It can load external font swfs,Now I am using TLFTextField,Eventhough I set a embedFonts = true, It still taking the device font,How to stop it.
In adobe Documentation it is mentioned that, TLFTextField takes fall back font if embedded font is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DF4` instead of `DF3` while embedding fonts using AnimateCC or flash. Also use `TextLayoutFormat` instead of `TextFormat`